# Using template.render() without a file reference

Tags: python, google-app-engine, template-engine

Is it possible to use template.render() without a file path?

I'd like to do dynamic string replacemnt for text properties in my datastore. Templating immediately came to mind. Perhaps there is another way? My thought was the following...

```
my_string = template.render(my_model.description,template_dict)
```

Comment: just found string.Template. that's likely the best answer, no?

Comment: There's also the simple old string formatting: `"a %s b" % some_str`. The new string formatting `"a {0} b"` only comes in with Python 2.6, while App Engine uses 2.5.

Comment: Ideally, it would act a lot like the webapp templating that utilizes a dictionary. Arbitrary string replacement is less flexible. This would be ideal... "Hello, {{name}}. You're cool."  {'name':'Superman'}

Comment: Yes, I think string.Template is your best bet, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the "google-app-engine" tag, I assume you are talking about the templating engine provided with `google.appengine.ext.webapp`? According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-BE/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html): "for your convenience, the webapp module includes Django's templating engine". So have a look at the [Django docs for templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/)...

As far as I can tell, you should be able to do something like the following (I am assuming `my_model.description` contains your template string?):

```
t = template.Template(my_model.description)
my_string = t.render(template.Context(template_dict))
```

(It might also be useful to have a look at the webapp code for [template.py](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/branches/1.2.1/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py))

Comment: That'll work unless the template string includes tags that will want to load other templates.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that (I'm actually not familiar with django templating ;-)). I don't know if the OP will want to do that. If he does, I suppose it should be possible to provide your own "loader"? (but I'll leave that to you ;-), or at least someone who has more experience with that)

Answer (score 0):

There's no officially-supported way to do use a non-file-based template with webapp's `template.render()`

Here's an **unsupported** way that works with 1.5.1 (and may well *not* work thereafter):

```
class StringTemplate(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    import django.template
    mytemplate = "<html>...</html>"
    t = django.template.Template(mytemplate)
    fake_path = os.path.abspath("main.py") # or any uploaded file
    template.template_cache[fake_path] = t
    self.response.out.write(template.render(fake_path, {})
```

`app.yaml` is used because the template cache uses the absolute path of a template as a key, so any real file will do as a fake template source. But that's an implementation detail that may well change.

Comment: app.yaml isn't a real file on App Engine; it's not uploaded with the application.

Comment: Works with dev_appserver! Thanks, fixed above.